# Get auto_increment ID from SQL Compact Edition

Tags: .net-3.5, sql-server-ce

I am prototyping an app using ASP.NET MVC and SQL Compact Edition on VS2008.  I have 2 entities that have have a many-to-many relationship with each other.  When I save objects to the database through hand-crafted SQL I need to find out what their ID is so I can drop a record into the mapping table between the two entities.  The auto_increment ID field is in fact the only unique identifier for the tables.  So after I've done my insert, how do I re-load the record and grab the newly assigned ID?

RE: Code-is-art, I am using the builtin SqlCeConnection, SqlCeCommand, and SqlCeDataReader objects from the .NET 3.5 library.

Comment: What library are you using to access your database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use "SELECT @@IDENTITY" in a subsequent call to the database.

Compact is single user access you don't need to worry about transactions etc to protect against other inserts.